# Will pods in pending status occupy resourceQuota?

Tags: kubernetes

I wanna know pods in pending status still occupy resourceQuota?

I wanna know how to find the code about pod occupy resourceQuota.
I feel it's hard to find the certain code show pod resource occupy resourceQuota(k8s code is numerous )

Comment: try installing metrics server and run `kubectl top pods -A`

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Pods in `Pending` state will occupy resource quota. The reason is that quotas are generally checked and updated at API resource creation. So the `Pod` object exists (even though it hasn't been scheduled), ergo it adds to your quota.

You can easily test this by creating a `ResourceQuota` and then try to create a `Pod` resource that you know cannot be scheduled. Apply the quota below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: ResourceQuota
metadata:
  name: quota
spec:
  hard:
    cpu: 1
```

And then create the `Pod` (this has an impossible node selector, so we know it wouldn't be scheduled) below:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  namespace: test
spec:
  nodeSelector:
    impossible: to-satisfy
  containers:
  - name: nginx
    image: nginx:1.14.2
    resources:
      requests:
        cpu: 0.5
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

You'll see the quota being consumed:

```bash
k get pods,resourcequota
NAME        READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
pod/nginx   0/1     Pending   0          63s

NAME                  AGE     REQUEST       LIMIT
resourcequota/quota   6m48s   cpu: 500m/1
```